# Filter the same payments by different persons - SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

can you please help me with the following problem :

i have a table `Payments` :

```
Id  ROLE    Payment
1   A       100
1   A       100
1   R       50
1   R       50
1   R       50
2   A       100
2   A       100
2   R       50
2   R       50
2   R       100
```

Now the ID is one cash loan ( so we have two of them). Role A/R means there are two ppls paying that loan (A-one guy, R- second guy).

Now i need to SUM all the payments for specific ID which is still ok, BUT when the payment for role A is same as for role R i want to count for SUM just one of them..

I was trying to solve it with inner join on the same table where id and payment is the same and role is different  but still have the problem that when i have this:

```
2   A   100
2   A   100
2   R   100
```

the result is not 100 but 200 ( i will count (A100,R100) = 100 , A100 = 100)

Thank you for any help

UPDATE:
@Giorgi Nakeuri -  for given example, the result should looke like :

```
ID     Payment
1      350
2      300
```

UPDATE : for better understanding : In the given example(for id 2)i have 100payment for R and A so we count it just once = 100, then i have one 100payment just for A = 100, and two payments 50 just for R = 100, 100+100+100 = 300 payment for id 2

Comment: What output should be for your test data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE ( ID INT, R CHAR(1), P INT )
INSERT  INTO @t
VALUES  ( 1, 'A', 100 ),
        ( 1, 'A', 100 ),
        ( 1, 'R', 50 ),
        ( 1, 'R', 50 ),
        ( 1, 'R', 50 ),
        ( 2, 'A', 100 ),
        ( 2, 'A', 100 ),
        ( 2, 'R', 50 ),
        ( 2, 'R', 50 ),
        ( 2, 'R', 100 );

WITH    cte
          AS ( SELECT   id ,
                        P ,
                        SUM(CASE WHEN R = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) cd1 ,
                        SUM(CASE WHEN R = 'R' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) cd2
               FROM     @t
               GROUP BY id ,
                        P
             )

    SELECT  ID ,
            SUM(P * CASE WHEN cd1 > cd2 THEN cd1 ELSE cd2 END) AS Sum
    FROM    cte
    GROUP BY ID
```

Output:

```
ID  Sum
1   350
2   300
```

Comment: Well this will indeed return the wanted result but i dont think its following the logic behind the result. If i just add two more 100 payments for R role for id 2 the result should be 400 but this will stil return 300

Comment: @Nightmaresux, see updates. In 2 I get 200. I think you have error in your test output.

Comment: No i dont, maybe i explain it badly. In the given example(id 2)i have 100payment for R and A so we count it just once = 100, then i have one 100payment just for A = 100, and two payments 50 just for R = 100, 100+100+100 = 300 :)

Comment: @Nightmaresux, ok you want to calc repeated couples just once. See final update

Comment: Cool , this is working with my test data, ill try to implement it and will let you know how it went. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to distinct the query?

SELECT distinct *yourField* from *yourTable*

Comment: It will just filter out the same values,i dont want to do that.